# Find two rational numbers $\frac ab$ satisfying $\mid \pi - \frac ab\mid < \frac{1}{\sqrt 5 b^2}.$

Tags: number-theory, periodic-functions, continued-fractions

Find two rational numbers $\frac ab$ satisfying
$$\mid \pi - \frac ab\mid < \frac{1}{\sqrt 5 b^2}.$$

I dont know how to find such rationals. IS there a method? or trial?

Comment: That's [Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory)). For a solution, look up continued fractions.

Comment: What about $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{355}{113}$, that is a well-known convergent of the continued fraction of $\pi$?

Comment: Also the even better know approximation $\tfrac{a}{b}=\tfrac{22}{7}$ for $\pi$ works.

Comment: @Servaes: that is the convergent *before* $\frac{355}{113}$ :D

Answer (score 2):

See theorem 20 on page 31 in Khinchin's little book, 
 out of three consecutive convergents to any fixed irrational number,
 at least one satisfies $|\mbox{error}| < 1 / q^2 \sqrt 5.$

$$ \pi :  3, 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 84, $$

$$  
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 & & 3 & & 7 & & 15 & & 1 & & 292 &  \\
\frac{0}{1} & \frac{1}{0} & & \frac{3}{1} &  &  \frac{22}{7} & &  \frac{333}{106}  & & \frac{355}{113} & &  \frac{103993}{33102}   
\end{array}
$$

3/1: $1/ \sqrt 5 \approx 0.447, |\mbox{error}| \approx 0.14159$ is smaller

22/7: $1/(49 \sqrt 5) \approx 0.0091268, |\mbox{error}| \approx 0.00126$ is smaller

333/106: $1/(11236 \sqrt 5) \approx 0.0000398, |\mbox{error}| \approx $0.0000832$ is BIGGER

355/113: $1/(12769 \sqrt 5) \approx 0.0000350, |\mbox{error}| \approx $0.000000266$ is  smaller

103993/33102: $1/(1095742404 \sqrt 5) \approx 4.08 \cdot 10^{-10},|\mbox{error}| \approx 5.7789 \cdot 10^{-10}$ is BIGGER

The better known result is simply that, if the next digit $a_{k+1} \geq 3,$ then the inequality holds because
$$  \left| \alpha - \frac{p_k}{q_k} \right| \leq \frac{1}{q_k^2 \; a_{k+1}}  $$
is first written down in the proof of Theorem 22, bottom of page 35. So, except for the pretend convergent $1/0$ that just starts the setup, we see how the convergents **just before** the digits $7,15,292$ all satisfy the desired inequality, and the one just before 292 is the best ( ratio of error to $1/q^2$).

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to get the continued fraction for $\pi$.  See [How to find continued fraction of pi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716944/how-to-find-continued-fraction-of-pi) .  Then work out as many convergents as necessary.  There is a recursive method for generating the numerators and denominators of the convergents, also explained in the answers in the link above.