# How does one come up with a Continued Fraction?

Tags: continued-fractions

All over the place on Wikipedia, I see a bunch of identities related to continued fractions, like
$$\arctan x=\cfrac{x}{1+\cfrac{x^2}{3+\cfrac{4x^2}{5+\cfrac{9x^2}{7+...}}}}$$
or
$$\pi=\cfrac{4}{1+\cfrac{1^2}{2+\cfrac{3^2}{2+\cfrac{5^2}{2+...}}}}$$
How does one verify these? I haven't even managed to prove a single one of them yet.

Furthermore, aside from *proving* them, how does one *derive* them? That is, how does one *come up with* something like this?

I know how to evaluate simpler continued fractions, like
$$\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+...}}}$$

But I don't know how to evaluate anything where the terms on the inside follow some other sort of sequence.

Can anyone provide a proof (or, preferably, a derivation) of one of the two identities above, or some other continued fraction identity? Can anybody give me some way to go about these types of problems?

Comment: [proof of the continued fraction of $e$](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~marin/une_autre_crypto/articles_et_extraits_livres/Cohn_H_A_Short_proof_of_the_simple_convergent_of_e.pdf).

Comment: There is a way to convert power series into continued fractions.

Comment: also, I feel [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716944/how-to-find-continued-fraction-of-pi) might answer yours

Comment: You might be interested in Thiele expansion (see e.g. [this](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=czHV-1bEFl0C&pg=PA326)), which is the CF analog of Taylor expansion. Another useful source of continued fractions are linear three-term recurrences: they can be suitably rearranged into continued fractions that converge to ratios of functions that are the solutions of the three-term recurrence, via [Pincherle's theorem](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=DQtpJaEs4NIC&pg=PA57).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note we have [Euler's continued fraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula), which states:

$$a_{0}+a_{0}a_{1}+a_{0}a_{1}a_{2}+\cdots +a_{0}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}\\=\cfrac  {a_{0}}{1-{\cfrac  {a_{1}}{1+a_{1}-{\cfrac  {a_{2}}{1+a_{2}-{\cfrac  {\ddots }{\ddots {\cfrac  {a_{{n-1}}}{1+a_{{n-1}}-{\cfrac  {a_{n}}{1+a_{n}}}}}}}}}}}}$$

This may easily be proven by induction and lends itself for easy conversion of a series into a fraction.  For example, we know that:

$$\arctan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-2)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

Set $a_0=x$ and inductively,

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+3}}{2n+3}\prod_{k=0}^n(a_k)^{-1}=-\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}x^2$$

And then after some algebra, you'll be able to derive

$$\arctan(x)=\cfrac{x}{1+\cfrac{x^2}{3+\cfrac{4x^2}{5+\cfrac{9x^2}{7+\ddots}}}}$$

Plug $x=1$ in and do some more algebra and you'll end up with the formula for $\pi$.

Comment: The "after some algebra, you'll be able to derive..." part is the crux of the matter. If one directly uses the Euler continued fraction formula + a simple equivalence transformation to change the denominators, one ends up with: $$\arctan x=\frac{x}{1+\frac{x^2}{3-x^2+\frac{(3x)^2}{5-3x^2+\frac{(5x)^2}{7-5x^2+\cdots}}}}$$But I am not aware of any simple transformation techniques to turn this into the form you provide

Comment: Sorry, but $\arctan(x) = x - x^3/3 + x^5/5 - \cdots$ with  $(-1)^n$ in the numerator instead of $(-2)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
http://dainoequinoziale.it/resources/sassolini/pifrazionecontinua.pdf
It is in Italian, but it explains in the simplest possible way how to go from Lord Brouncker continued fraction to the Gregory-Leibniz series to calculate Pi.