# How does one come up with the continued fraction for the arctangent? $\arctan x=\frac{x}{1+}\frac{x^2}{3+}\frac{(2x)^2}{5+}\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, proof-explanation, continued-fractions

$\newcommand{\K}{\operatorname{\large{K}}}$The question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2349479/815585). However, I find the accepted answer unsatisfactory since it details all the parts which are, in my opinion, trivial, and the one step it doesn't elaborate on is precisely the step I consider non-trivial. I am a bit stuck, so I'd like to ask here. I’ll be using Gauss’ Kettenbrücher K-notation for continued fractions, analogous to the $\sum,\prod$ notations.

We know that: $$\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\cdots$$For $|x|\lt1$ and we know Euler's continued fraction formula: $$a_0\left(1+\K_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-a_n}{1+a_n}\right)^{-1}=a_0+a_0a_1+a_0a_1a_2+\cdots$$So it is quite easy to find $a_0=x,\,a_n=-\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}x^2$ as suitable for the arctangent, to get: $$\arctan x=x\left(1+\K_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}x^2}{1-\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}x^2}\right)^{-1}=\cfrac{x}{1+\cfrac{\frac{1}{3}x^2}{1-\frac{1}{3}x^2+\cfrac{\frac{3}{5}x^2}{1-\frac{3}{5}x^2+\cdots}}}$$And by clearing the denominators we obtain: $$\tag{1}\arctan x=\cfrac{x}{1+\cfrac{x^2}{3-x^2+\cfrac{(3x)^2}{5-3x^2+\cdots}}}$$But the accepted answer to the linked post claims a different fraction follows. Apparently, if one uses Euler's formula - with the same coefficients I used - it is a matter of simple algebra to arrive at: $$\tag{2}x\left(1+\K_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}x^2}{1-\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}x^2}\right)^{-1}\overset{?}{=}\cfrac{x}{1+\cfrac{x^2}{3+\cfrac{(2x)^2}{5+\cfrac{(3x)^2}{7+\cdots}}}}$$

This is corroborated by Wikipedia. Unfortunately I am at a complete loss as to how to go from $(1)$ to $(2)$. One thing I have noticed - it suffices to show: $$\K_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(nx)^2}{2n+1}=\K_{n=1}^\infty\frac{((2n-1)x)^2}{(2n+1)-(2n-1)x^2}=\K_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n^2x-(n-1)^2x)^2}{(n+1)^2-n^2-(nx)^2+((n-1)x)^2}$$As $2n-1=n^2-(n-1)^2$, which seems half-promising, but I just don't see the trick needed to procede.

Other than equivalence transformations given by clearing denominators, I don't know how to manipulate continued fractions. What are we supposed to do here?

Note: I see that it is also possible to prove this result, and many others, using the Gauss continued fraction identities for the hypergeometric functions. I have never studied the hypergeometric functions: if you can answer using them, I’d really appreciate it if the answer was written in such a way that avoids the general theory. But, that shouldn’t be necessary, since the accepted answer to the linked post claims the result follows from “algebra”.

Comment: Note: the title is using a common continued fraction notation. Please do not edit the title by changing the positions of the pluses and fractions!

Comment: I'm so sorry! Never seen this notation before, good to know :)

Comment: @lisyarus No worries!

Comment: This does not appear to be a matter of simple algebra. I think using Gauss hypergeometric function is necessary. You should consider the function $f(x) =(\arctan\sqrt{x}) /\sqrt{x} =1-\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{5}-\dots$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for your comment, I feel as if the answerer in the linked post made some oversight and rather intended to say: “some simple algebra... yields: [the ‘easy’ arctan fraction]”. I will have a look at Gauss’ technique. I’m curious - what did you intend I gain from the consideration of $\arctan(\sqrt{x})/\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: Using square roots reduces the powers of $x$ and you get the series in form $\sum a_nx^n$ instead of $\sum a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$. I find it simpler when doing calculations with pen and paper. But that's just a personal view.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Sir, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4517287/815585) question of mine was partly inspired by [this](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/04/continued-fraction-expansion-of-tanx.html?m=0#.YwYaK8BHmEf) great blog post of yours. You derive the tangent continued fraction via a recurrence in $G(n,x)$, and you get a sequence of continued fractions for $G(0,x)$. Then, you show in a different blog post that the continued fraction is convergent. However you also note that $\lim_nG(n,x)=1$ is a key condition for the *resulting convergent expression to equal $G(0,x)$*. (cont.)

Comment: @ParamanandSingh But the notion of, under what conditions can we say the convergent fraction converges to the original value - the base of the recurrence, $G(0,x)$ - is precisely the question I ask (linked). I don’t understand why $\lim_n G(n,x)=1$ is needed/sufficient, but I trust that you’re right: it seems like you would be able to make a very meaningful contribution to that question of mine. I would greatly appreciate any comment.

Comment: I have since understood the condition $G(n,x)\to1$. Perhaps you know some general theory, all thoughts are appreciated

Comment: The general theory of convergence is rather difficult. I checked a definitive reference *Analytic theory of continued fractions* by H. S. Wall which gives a chapter full treatment of Gauss continued fraction. I will try to get some stuff from there and present it as an answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Nice reference, I really appreciate anything you can find! Really, I wish for a way to check both convergence and *convergence to the right thing* in one step

Comment: It is simpler to apply the ideas given in [this blog post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/05/irrationality-of-pi-lamberts-proof.html?m=0) and deduce that if $p_n/q_n$ is the $n$-th convergent for continued fraction related to $G(0,x)$ then $$\left|G(0,x)-\frac{p_n} {q_n} \right|\leq K(G(n, x)-1) $$ for some constant $K$ and all sufficiently large values of $n$. Thus the ratio $p_n/q_n$ tends to $G(0,x)$.

Comment: The theory of Gauss continued fraction in my reference text is a bit too long to include here as answer (or better put it like I have not yet been able to squeeze that to the size of an answer).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ok, thanks anyway. Did any quick conditions appear in that reference text, as in, statements along the lines of what I wrote as “observations” in the question I linked? I found some fairly easy conditions for the fraction to converge to the *desired* value, I wonder if harder ones have been found

Comment: It may well be that none of them are quick, I realise!

Comment: I checked your linked question and there you mention the condition that $|q_n|$ should be increasing and $\alpha_n\to 0$. Just to let you know both these are met in case of continued fraction for $\tan x$ as well as $\arctan x$. My linked blog post (in comments) gives a criteria when the sequence $q_n$ will increase.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, I was very happy to discover your analysis of the case $a_n\ge b_n+1$, it is very useful.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_continued_fraction_formula

Answer (score 2):

For reference, here is a computation using generating functions. We show that $$\cfrac{z}{1+\cfrac{z^2}{3+\cfrac{(2z)^2}{5+\cfrac{(3z)^2}{7+\dots}}}}$$ exists and equals $\arctan z$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $1+z^2\notin\mathbb{R}_{\leqslant 0}$.

The above [equals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Fundamental_recurrence_formulas) $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(P_n/Q_n)$, where the vectors $R_n=(P_n,Q_n)$ satisfy $$R_0=(0,1),\quad R_1=(z,1),\quad R_{n+1}=(2n+1)R_n+(nz)^2 R_{n-1}\quad(n>0)$$ or, if we put $R_n=n!S_n$, so that $S(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n t^n$ exists if $|t|$ is small enough, $$(n+1)S_{n+1}=(2n+1)S_n+nz^2 S_{n-1}\quad(n>0)$$ which, multiplied by $t^n$ and summed over $n$, gives $$S'(t)-S_1=2tS'(t)+S(t)-S_0+z^2\big(t^2 S'(t)+tS(t)\big),$$ i.e. $(1-2t-z^2 t^2)S'(t)-(1+z^2 t)S(t)=S_1-S_0$. The solution with $S(0)=S_0$ is $$S(t)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-2t-z^2 t^2}}\left(S_0+(S_1-S_0)\int_0^t\frac{d\tau}{\sqrt{1-2\tau-z^2\tau^2}}\right)$$ (let's postpone the computation of the integral). The singularities (branch points) of $S(t)$ are $$t_\pm=\frac1{1\pm\sqrt{1+z^2}},\qquad|t_+|<|t_-|;$$ the *singularity analysis* of $S(t)$ as $t\to t_+$ (as covered in [*Analytic Combinatorics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_Combinatorics) by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick, chapter VI) shows that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n/(t_+^n\sqrt{n})$ exists, and if $S(t)=\big(P(t),Q(t)\big)$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{Q_n}=\lim_{t\to t_+}\frac{P(t)}{Q(t)}=z\int_0^{t_+}\frac{d\tau}{\sqrt{1-2\tau-z^2\tau^2}},$$ with $t\to t_+$ radially (say). Now it's time to evaluate the integral *and get the expected result*.

Comment: I just realised I never responded to this beyond a simple upvote. I apologise. That's a good answer, I just am not familiar with the analytic techniques near the end. Thanks anyway, I may get it one day after having studied ODEs in more detail