# What is the simple continued fraction of $τ$ ($2π$)?

Tags: pi, continued-fractions

I cannot find any information on Google or Wolfram Mathworld to answer this question. I also don't have the skills to calculate it myself so I thought it would be good if someone with this knowledge could share it here.

Comment: If you have absolutely no basic understanding in this field, why not look for some textbooks first? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: We don't require people to find the answers in textbooks instead of asking here, though. It just needs to be a good question that hasn't been answered yet. OP has 43k rep on stackoverflow so they're pretty familiar with how stackexchange works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find continued fraction of pi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716944/how-to-find-continued-fraction-of-pi) — my answer there explains briefly how to calculate continued fractions, which is just straightforward arithmetic once you know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$2\pi \approx
6+\cfrac{1}{
3+\cfrac{1}{
1+\cfrac{1}{
1+\cfrac{1}{
7+\cfrac{1}{
2+\cfrac{1}{
146+\cfrac{1}{
3+\cfrac{1}{
1+\cfrac{1}{
138+\cdots}}}}}}}}}$$

In 
[How to find continued fraction of pi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716944/how-to-find-continued-fraction-of-pi)
I explained how to calculate a simple continued fraction, using $\pi$ as an example.  It's straightforward arithmetic and does not require any theory.

Once we have a few terms, we can search for them in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, which produces sequence [A058291](https://oeis.org/A058291), “Continued fraction for 2 Pi”.  This page gives 97 terms, has a link to a listing of 20,000 terms, and other links to more information.